# Gem Daemons - How to run several different daemons

Tags: ruby, daemon

Basically I just want to run several daemons in my ruby script :

```
require 'daemons'

Daemons.run path_1, { :ARGV => ['start'], :app_name => 'app1', :multiple => true, ... }
Daemons.run path_2, { :ARGV => ['start'], :app_name => 'app2', :multiple => true, ... }
```

But the second Daemons.run is never called when ARGV[0] == 'start' (works perfectly with 'status'/'stop'). What is the right way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

from http://daemons.rubyforge.org

3- Control a bunch of daemons from another application

Layout: you have an application my_app.rb that wants to run a bunch of server tasks as daemon processes.

```
# this is my_app.rb

require 'rubygems'        # if you use RubyGems
require 'daemons'

task1 = Daemons.call(:multiple => true) do
  # first server task

  loop {
    conn = accept_conn()
    serve(conn)
  }
end

task2 = Daemons.call do
  # second server task

  loop {
    something_different()
  }
end

# the parent process continues to run

# we can even control our tasks, for example stop them
task1.stop
task2.stop

exit
```

does it fit?